# Cancel Task inside task when timed out. C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to run collection of tasks. I have a `procesing object model`, which properties I don't know. That's is why I've created a child of this class. I have a collection of `ProcesingTask` objects. This is my code:

```
 public sealed class ProcessingTask : ProcessingObject
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource cancelToken;
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        public int TimeOut {private get; set; }
        public int ProcessObjectID { get; private set; }         
        public Task ProcessObjectTask { get; private set; }
        public QueueObject queueObject { private get; set; }
        public ProcessingTask(int processObjectID)
        {          
            this.ProcessObjectID = processObjectID;
            ResetTask();               
        }
    private void InitialTimeOut()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeOut);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimedOut);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void TimedOut(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
         cancelToken.Cancel();
         Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} was timed out...", ProcessObjectID);
        _timer.Stop();            
    }
    public void ResetTask()
    {
        cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ProcessObjectTask = new Task(() => DoTaskWork(), cancelToken.Token);            
    }
    public void DoTaskWork()
    {
        InitialTimeOut();     
        Random rand = new Random();
        int operationTime = rand.Next(2000, 20000);               
        Thread.Sleep(operationTime);
        _timer.Stop();          
         Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} was finished...", ProcessObjectID);            
    }       
}

public class CustomThreadPool
    {
        private IList<ProcessingTask> _processingTasks;      
        public CustomThreadPool(List<ProcessingTask> processingObjects)
        {           
            this._processingTasks = processingObjects;
        }
        public void RunThreadPool(Queue<QueueObject> queue, int batchSize)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= batchSize; i++)
            {
                QueueObject queueObject = queue.ToArray().ToList().FirstOrDefault();

                ProcessingTask task = _processingTasks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessObjectID == queueObject.QueueObjectId);                
                task.queueObject = queue.Dequeue();
                task.TimeOut = 3000;
                task.ProcessObjectTask.Start();   
            }
        }

        public void WaitAll()
        {
            var tasks = _processingTasks.Select(x => x.ProcessObjectTask).ToArray();           
            Task.WaitAll(tasks); 
        }
    }
```

I need to stop `DoTaskWork()` if running time was timed out. I'm trying to use `timer` and `CancellationToken`. But `DoTaskWork()` still doing his job after `TimedOut()`. Is any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with a usage example?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you send the cancel signal, you don't do anything with that in `DoTaskWork`

```
public void DoTaskWork()
{
    InitialTimeOut();     
    Random rand = new Random();
    int operationTime = rand.Next(2000, 20000);

    // Thread.Sleep(operationTime); // this imitates a non-responsive operation

    // but this imitates a responsive operation:
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested
      && stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < operationTime)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    _timer.Stop();          
     Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} was finished...", ProcessObjectID);            
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I need to abort download file operation, for example?

Comment: Normally downloading is performed in small chunks (eg. using a 4K buffer) so you can check the cancellation between them. But whatever you do you need to check the cancellation status just "often enough" to be responsive. Besides, I would differentiate *cancellation* and *abortion*. Abort is a forced operation, can be used to kill non-responsive tasks (eg. by `Thread.Abort`). But this this should be avoided at all costs if possible because it can cause serious problems: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your method `DoTaskWork()` accordingly.

Assume this as a sample. I am assuming that your thead is doing some continuos work rather just sleep. Otherwise you can use abort method which will just abort the thread even if its in sleep mode.

```
public void DoTaskWork()
    {
        InitialTimeOut();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int operationTime = rand.Next(2000, 20000);
        while (true)
        {
            if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cancellation requested.");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(operationTime);
        }
        _timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} was finished...", ProcessObjectID);
    }
```